# SQL Server: IsMSShipped = 0 but system SPs still returned

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME (sc.object_id) as "schema", OBJECT_NAME(sc.object_id) as "name", sc.*   
-- FROM syscomments sc 
FROM sys.sql_modules sc 
WHERE "Definition" LIKE '%raiserror%'
and
OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'IsMSShipped') = 0
and
OBJECT_NAME(sc.object_id) like '%diagram%'
```

Why is this query returning these SPs? Aren't they from Microsoft?

sp_helpdiagramdefinition
sp_creatediagram
sp_renamediagram
sp_alterdiagram
sp_dropdiagram

Comment: They dont come up when I run that command..   although I would agree they sound like MS ones

Comment: @BugFinder They're optional.  They only get installed if you click on the [Database Diagrams] folder in SSMS.

Comment: The diagramming objects live in a twilight zone where they're "sort of" system objects, but also "sort of" not since Management Studio is the only thing that creates and uses them (and that only on demand). It chooses not to mark them as system objects, although it could. As far as SQL Server itself is concerned, these are no more special than your average user object. (And the fact that their names start with `sp_` is arguably a mistake, same as for any other user-defined stored procedure.)

Answer (score 1):

**IsMSShipped** is set to 1 for any object that was created during SQL Server's installation.  The Diagram objects are optional and are only added to a database after the initial installation.

In other words, although they *are* from MS, they are not *Shipped* from MS (at least not as MS is defining "Shipped").

Yes I know, it's dumb, everyone gets tripped up by this at least once.  They should have called it something like `IsMSInstalled` instead.  Just goes to show the importance of picking good names.

The SOP way to handle this is to *also* filter on the schema ("sys" is always schema_id 4).

Comment: IsMSShipped is also set for e.g. replication objects which are only added to DBs after their initial creation (or at least, this was certainly true in the ~2008 time frame. Haven't re-verified recently)

Comment: You can also tag your procedures as MSShipped through the undocumented sp_MS_marksystemobject.

Comment: But in my case it says "dbo", not "sys" for schema name.

Comment: See [this accepted answer from 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6521747/15498) where we were discussing that replication objects do get marked as MS Shipped.

Comment: @peter.petrov Yeah, you're right.  I forgot that the Diagram objects are grandfathered (or something) into .dbo.  I have to add a special filter for '*diagram*'.  Actually, I hate the diagram objects and I try to make sure they aren't in any actual DB that I am using. If I need the diagram facility, I make a metadata-only copy of my DB and use it there.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yep, I forgot that too.  Basically, `IsMSShipped` isn't very consistent at all.